# Set theory proof with contrapositive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

A, B, and C are subsets of a universal set U.

Prove $(A-C) \cap B \neq \emptyset \to A \cap B \not\subseteq C$.

I figured the best way to prove that is the contrapositive, I got this far:

Contrapositive: $A \cap B \subseteq C \to (A-C) \cap B = \emptyset$

$\forall x \in U, x \in A \land x \in B \to x \in C$.

Now I'm stuck, and I'm not sure how to go from there. I can see that I need to show that A-C is removing all elements in the intersection, but I can't figure out how I can do that from the conditional.

I tried just proving it directly, without the contrapositive, but that didn't work either, there I didn't even know how to start.

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrapositive is probably a good idea.  Assume $A\cap B\subseteq C$ and prove $(A-C)\cap B=\emptyset$ by contradiction.

Suppose $x\in(A-C)\cap B$, then $x\in A-C$ and $x\in B$.  So $x\in A$ and $x\not\in C$.

Since $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ we have $x\in A\cap B$.

Since $A\cap B\subseteq C$ we have $x\in C$.

But we already have $x\not\in C$, so this is a contradiction.  Therefore $(A-C)\cap B=\emptyset$.

---

Direct proof is actually also quite easy.

Assume $(A-C)\cap B$ is not empty, then it contains an element $x$.

This means $x\in A$ and $x\not\in C$ and $x\in B$.

Therefore $x\in A\cap B$ and $x\not\in C$, so $A\cap B$ is not a subset of $C$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand so much better now! Thank you!